# how does ssh connect to master node on GCP?

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, google-compute-engine, kubectl

I got the problem about how to connect to the master node on GCP. I want to build a directory in this master node,so I need to connect to it via ssh or any other method.But I found so many pages on browsers ,they can't work for me . This is following situation I met:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxAWJ.jpg)

Above is the terminal I entered command on GCP VM . when I wanted to ssh into this master node , I got the permission error. Could anyone help me ?I will appreciate with you very much.

Comment: IME, especially in hosted environments like GKE or EKS, you _can't_ directly ssh to nodes; but at the same time, pods also can't access the host filesystem, so it doesn't especially matter.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's due to the Wrong SSH key or Default key permission being denied.

If that node is running into the GCP itself you can go to the instances section and there will be an option to SSH directly instead of running the command from the browser shell.

Go to instances to list all running instances and find the one and click on the SSH button it will do the SSH for you without the key.